# SQL Server Remote Tunnel Applications

Tags: sql-server, tunneling

I would like to know if there are some type of applications that allows me to access SQL Server in my local server remotely from a desktop application in one of my other branches through Internet;

I've already read about accessing it by using public IP; but that is too difficulty for me as I cant get public IP for my server easily. Plus I cant get access to the routers to set ports required;

Are there are other applications (even paid ones) that provide some sort of tunnels to access my SQL Server database remotely?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a VPN solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking for a Sql Server solution here. Any generic correctly configured VPN solution will work. However that is not in and of itself an easy configuration and, depending on your business, your security department may expressly forbid.

Your best bet is to use some sort of Desktop sharing solution TBH, e.g. Splashtop, TeamViewer etc. Again, your security department may not be too happy with such a 'solution' either.

Comment: Thanks @Rachel ; but Desktop sharing solution is not Possible as i want to add transactions to my SQL server database form  Desktop App located in an other branch through internet.  ; For Now the Security is a priority as i am running simple Order Application.

Comment: So if You Know any VPN app that allows me to execute Queries directly Against my Database ??

Comment: Pretty much all correctly configured VPN solutions will allow you to do that. That said, asking to suggest or for recommendations on various VPN solutions is not the remit for Stack Overflow, as that then comes down to opinion and not fact. In addition they're not usually things you can set up on the fly. If you have a security department then you can bet your bottom dollar they'll be VERY involved in anything you try to do that'll potentially 'punch a hole' through whatever firewall protections they have configured.

Comment: You should bring this up to your manager\boss and your security department next.